# Issue with NoSql data model

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, nosql

As being newbie, facing issues with the data modelling on the Cassandra data model. We are planning to use the Cassandra for the reporting purpose. In the reporting we need to filter data by multiple parameters. Let's say We have a column family

```
Create table cf_data
(
   Date varchar,
   Attribute1 varchar, 
   Attribute2 varchar,
   Attribute3 varchar,
   Attribute4 varchar,
   Attribute5 varchar,
   Attribute6 varchar,
   Primary Key(Date)
)
```

We need to support query like

```
Select * from cf_date where date = '2015-02-02' and Attribute1 in ('asdf','assf','asdf') and Attribute1 in ('wewer','werwe') and Attribute2 in ('sdfsd','werwe') and Attribute3 in ('weryewu','ghjghjh')
```

I know we need to respect the primary key restrictions while querying the column family. Cassandra internal storage works like

```
SortedMap<String,SortedMap<Key,Value>>
```

NoSQL works on the principle of storing denormalized data as per the access pattern. If I need to satisfy the above query how should I model the column family. From report UI, user can select the values from Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3.... etc as a drop down. One option could be using Spark on top of the Cassandra node to support SQL queries but it's better the model the column family as Cassandra expects.

Any pointers ??

Comment: what is the nature of the data you are storing?

Comment: It's financial time series data. Stock exchange trading information is saved so we can say it's time series data. Most of calculations are performed on the historical and current data. All the calculations can not be performed in advance. Some calculations are performed real time based on the input from user.

Comment: may i have some insert example so I can suggest you new structure

Answer (score 1):

From the Datastax CQL documentation:

"Under most conditions, using IN in the WHERE clause is not recommended. Using IN can degrade performance because usually many nodes must be queried."

If you need to use Spark to support SQL queries, you may be better off using a proper SQL database. Just because NoSQL is a fad, you don't need to follow it. Not all data can be efficiently modeled in all NoSQL DBs.

One other inefficient option for you is to query without the attributes itself and code the filtering in the application, at the risk of creating a large latency in response. If the reports are not to be created in real time or near real-time, then you should be good.